# Choosing different colors for this loading dots script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a 10 loading dots animation script.

As you can see we can choose a single color for all dots but, I want to choose different colors for each dot, I have tried to create unique dots divs and take the control of their colors in CSS but that way the animation crashes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the original code:

```js
TweenMax.staggerTo(".dots", 2, {
  x: 220,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  repeat: -1,
  ease: SlowMo.ease.config(0.3, 0.2, false)
}, 0.25);
TweenMax.staggerFrom(".dots", 2, {
  opacity: 0,
  scale: 0.7,
  repeat: -1,
  ease: SlowMo.ease.config(0.3, 0.2, true)
}, 0.25);
```

```css
html {
  width: 260px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.container {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d0c9d8;
  opacity: 1;
  left: -120px;
}


.dotss {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fcba03;
  opacity: 1;
  left: -120px;
}

.link {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "[nth-child() Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)" .

> The nth-child pseudo-class is specified with a single argument, which
>   represents the pattern for matching elements.

For your case;

```js
TweenMax.staggerTo(".dots", 2, {
  x: 220,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  repeat: -1,
  ease: SlowMo.ease.config(0.3, 0.2, false)
}, 0.25);
TweenMax.staggerFrom(".dots", 2, {
  opacity: 0,
  scale: 0.7,
  repeat: -1,
  ease: SlowMo.ease.config(0.3, 0.2, true)
}, 0.25);
```

```css
html {
  width: 260px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.container {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d0c9d8;
  opacity: 1;
  left: -120px;
}

 .dots:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: red;
}

 .dots:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.dotss {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fcba03;
  opacity: 1;
  left: -120px;
}

.link {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```